# Find the largest value of a list of lists

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to find the largest value of a list of lists?
For example

```
[[1; 2; 3; -4; -2; 0]; [1; 2; -5; -3; -1]]
```

Will ouput: `3`

Comment: Loop over each list while keeping track of the highest value. This could be done easily with a fold.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Should mention I just started learning this language :) I don't really know any specific vocabulary or stuff like that

Comment: Which part of what I said do you not get? I can try to explain.

Comment: I don't know OCAML, btw, but this question is pretty much language agnostic. Are you a beginner programmer or just new to the language?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't know what you mean by "fold". I was thinking of using pattern matching but it seems like it would be nightmareish

Comment: A fold is how you loop in functional programming, which OCAML is geared towards iirc. If you're going to program in functional languages, understanding folds/reductions is 100% necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of using pattern matching but it seems like it would be nightmareish

```
let rec lmax list = match list with
    | [] -> None
    | x :: xs -> Pervasives.max (Some x) (lmax xs)
```

But the function is not tail-recursive. 
The order of evaluation among function arguments is undefined, but basically you compute things like this:

```
-> Evaluate (Some x)
-> Evaluate (lmax xs)
   ...recursion...
<- Then, compute max
```

We have to compute and remember intermediate values for each call to `lmax`.
Another approach, is to use an auxiliary recursive function `aux`, which takes an *accumulator* value `acc`:

```
let lmax list = 
  let rec aux list acc = match list with
    | [] -> acc
    | x :: xs -> (aux xs (Pervasives.max acc (Some x)))
  in (aux list None)
```

Then, we don't need to store intermediate values:

```
-> Evaluate xs
-> Compute max of current acc with (Some x)
-> ...recursion...
```

The recursive call is going to compute the result for current values, there is no need to remember intermediate values, which makes the recursive call iterative.

#### Fold

The above is a common pattern that can be abstracted away with higher-order functions, known as *fold* (or *reduce*). There are two kinds of *fold*: the first one above is a *right fold*, the one with an accumulator is a *left fold*.
They take a reducing function, which computes a new result based on a previous result and a value, as well as an initial result (for empty lists).
Both kinds of fold compute the same result when the reducing function is associative, and due to its tail-recursive implementation, the left fold is recommended whenever possible.
The right fold is used when the reducing function is right associative, like `cons`. Here is a reimplementation of `List.map`:

```
let my_map fn list = List.fold_right (fun x xs -> (fn x) :: xs) list []
```

#### Lmax

And so, you can compute the maximum of a list using a left fold:

```
let lmax list = 
  List.fold_left  
    (fun max x -> Pervasives.max max (Some x))
    None
    list
```

The `option` type is necessary because there is no maximum for empty lists (you could return the most negative integer too).

#### LLmax

Now, you can also compute the maximum of a list of lists using a fold:

```
let llmax list =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun max list -> Pervasives.max max (lmax list))
    None 
    list;;
```

For each element of the list of lists, we compute the maximum thanks to `lmax` and produce the maximum value seen so far.

```
llmax [[1; 2; 3; -4; -2; 0]; [1; 2; -5; -3; -1]]
- : int option = Some 3
```

#### LL...max

If you want to generalize, you can write a `foldmax` function which is parameterized by a function which computes the maximum value of an element of a list:

```
let foldmax fn list =
  List.fold_left
  (fun max x -> Pervasives.max max (fn x))
  None
  list

val foldmax : ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b option = <fun>
```

Finally, you can rewrite `lmax`, `llmax` (`lllmax`, and so on) using this auxiliary function:

```
let lmax list = foldmax (fun x -> Some x) list
let llmax list = foldmax lmax list
let lllmax list = foldmax llmax list
```

Answer (score 1):

In an imperative/procedural language you might loop through the list and compare to a maximum number, i.e.

```
def max(lst):
  max = None
  for l in lst:
     for x in l:
        if max is None or x > max:
          max = x
  return max
```

(Clearly not idiomatic, just making this as clear a possible)

In OCaml, you would do something similar, but using something called a "fold" (a function), which is sort of an abstraction over the above idea.

```
let max list = 
  let f max x = 
    match max with
    | None -> Some x
    | Some m -> if m > x then Some m else Some x
  in
  List.fold_left f None (List.flatten list)
```

Comment: you mean List.fold_left, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
let max l =
  List.fold_left (fun max x ->
    Pervasives.max  max (Some x)
  ) None (List.flatten l)
```

**Test**

```
#  max [[1; 2; 3; -4; -2; 0]; [1; 2; -5; -3; -1]];;
- : int option = Some 3

# max [];;
- : 'a option = None
```

**Comments**

Pervasives.max found the max of two options :

```
# Pervasives.max None (Some (-1));;
- : int option = Some (-1)
```

List.flatten : Concatenate a list of lists

```
# List.flatten [[1; 2; 3; -4; -2; 0]; [1; 2; -5; -3; -1]];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; -4; -2; 0; 1; 2; -5; -3; -1]
```